# Como converter um Mono<MeuObjeto> para MeuObjeto em Spring Webflux

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Estou usando Spring WebClient para fazer uma requisição em uma API de terceiro. Esse trecho está da seguinte forma:

```
private Mono<MeuObjeto> getObjeto() {
    WebClient webClient = WebClient.create(url);

    return webClient.get()
            .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
                    .path(uri)
                    .queryParam("base", base)
                    .queryParam("access_key", apiKey)
                    .build())
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(MeuObjeto.class);
}
```

Tentei recuperar MeuObjeto usando o método `block`, da seguinte forma `MeuObjeto obj = monoMeuObjeto.block();`, porém obtive o seguinte erro:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-epoll-2
at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:83) ~[reactor-core-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14]
Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:
```

Estou aprendendo a criar aplicação com `Spring Webflux` e creio que a função block seja bloqueante, por isso ocorre o erro citado acima. A dúvida que não quer calar, qual é a forma correta de acessar o objeto contido em um `mono/flux`?

Answer (score -1):

Não tenho conhecimento em Mono mas sugiro que utilize RestTemplate
segue um exemplo:

```
 RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
        try {
            return template.getForEntity("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + city
                    + "&appid=b3cb5187ca32d8ba0e4c5aa3c520f2d4", Object.class);
        } catch (HttpStatusCodeException exception) {
            return exception.getResponseBodyAsString();
```

Comment: Talvez vc não tenha entendido a pergunta, mas o que preciso diz respeito a programação reativa.